# What are the differences between an MDB and SDF file?

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access, sql-server-ce, oledb

I am developing a standalone .NET application that currently uses an SQLite Database, but I want to port this to something else because i'm not happy with it's performance.

I would like to know which one would be better for use instead? An Access Database File or a SQL Server Compact Database File?

Which one would give the best performance and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally used Sql Server compact edition in place of SQLite. And it worked well.

You can find detailed comparison of both the databases here:
http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/24-27/Access-vs-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Compact-Embedded-Database

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion the choice between the two should be more related to evolution and maintenance of your application rather than pure / raw performances.

If you go for `SQL Compact` you will be using a programming model much closer to the real SQL Server one and in case you will need to scale your application to use the real `SQL Server` ( I know `Compact` is also a real version, but is embedded, in-process zero configuration one), you will have little pain.